# Declaration of a hashtable with key, value

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I'm in C# 2.0.

I would like to know if it is possible to declare a `Hashtable` const initiated with key & values. I know that it is possible with arrays:

```
public  static string[] ColumnsNames = 
{ "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"
, "string5", "string6", "string7" };
```

but how can we do that with Hashtables.

Comment: You need a const or static field? Const is not available for `Hashtable`

Comment: @Nabil Koroghli - Why exactly do you want to do this?  I should point out the string[] is not constant.

Comment: @Nabil Koroghli - You do understand you could use collection initializers without it being a static variable right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It cannot be done in C# 2.0. The language does not support it. The language specification is [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/f/98fdf0c7-2bbd-40d3-9fd1-5a4159fa8044/csharp%25202.0%2520specification_sept_2005.doc&ei=r3QlTpKjG8exhQenuI31CQ&usg=AFQjCNEFwD5nwtV7dLgz3PiYnF19ZkMB-Q) and there is no mention of inline dictionary initialisation.

C# 3.0 does allow dictionary initialisation similar to the array initialisation you described in your question (language spec [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%2520language%2520specification.doc&rct=j&q=c#%203%20language%20specification&ei=l3UlTuSAKI6bhQfr9IH8CQ&usg=AFQjCNGXik09_Rn-k0FGHG-A6v1EX3RLyA)). Here is an example:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"key1", "value1"},
    {"key2", "value2"}
};
```

Answer (score 8):

It's easy to create a static readonly field with C# 3 [*collection initializers*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), which can still target .NET 2. Using a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of a `Hashtable` though (don't use the nongeneric collections unless you really have to<sup>1</sup>).

It isn't a compile-time constant that you can declare with `const`, but I'm hoping you weren't *really* after `const`.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Foo
    = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Foo", "Bar" },
    { "Key", "Value" },
    { "Something", "Else" }
};
```

There's nothing similar in C# 2, if you really have to use that. Are you really still using Visual Studio 2005? Don't forget that you can still target .NET 2 with C# 3 and 4...

EDIT: If you *really* want to do it with C# 2 and hashtables, you could write a static method like this:

```
public static Hashtable CreateHashtable(params object[] keysAndValues)
{
    if ((keysAndValues.Length % 2) != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Must have an even number of keys/values");
    }
    Hashtable ret = new Hashtable();
    for (int i = 0; i < keysAndValues.Length; i += 2)
    {
        ret[keysAndValues[i]] = keysAndValues[i + 1];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then:

```
private static readonly Hashtable Foo = HashtableHelper.CreateHashtable(
    "key1", "value1", "key2", 10, "key3", 50);
```

I'd really not recommend that though...

---

<sup>1</sup> The same syntax will work with `Hashtable` if you're using C# 3, but it's really, really worth using the generic collections if you possibly can.

Comment: It's not in line, but an option for C# 2 is to instantiate and fill your static Hashtable or Dictionary in a static constructor.  This has the same net effect of having a static member initialised prior to use.

Comment: This is not constant, it's readonly. You can't use it where constant expressions are required like in attributes.

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour: I've added a little in the answer for that, but I don't think the OP really wanted const, given that they said "I know you can do it with arrays" which also aren't constant expressions. (Arrays *can* be used in attributes, but still aren't constants.)

Comment: @JonSkeet
Ok I see now. The OP asked "possible to declare a Hashtable const" and is why it's  referenced as 'const hashtable' on search engine even though OP code suggest he just want static/readonly behavior. And I just realized who answered the question.

Answer (score 8):

Believe this should work.

```
public Hashtable hash = new Hashtable()
{
  { "string1", 1 },
  { "string2", 2 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
Dictionary<string, string> DDD = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "A", "B" }, { "X", "Y" }, { "Z", "A" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `Dictionary`. On average the `Hastable` is about *1/3 slower than the Dictionary* (mainly due to implementation). Further it is *obsolete*.

Comment: I mean, that's not really what the question asked. If you're going to answer a 6+ year old question with an updated answer, you could at least answer the question along that line of thinking-- e.g. recommending a `ReadOnlyDictionary` or something.